# Will a serverside redirect (HttpResponse.Redirect) hit the load balancer again?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, load-balancing

The Web server is behind a load balancer . I'am doing a HttpResponse.Redirect("anotherpage") . 
Will this redirect again go through the load balancer ? I'm confused as this is a serverside redirect , and not a redirect from the client .

I want to know this to determine if the redirected url is served by a different web server as determined by the load balancer .

Comment: `HttpResponse.Redirect` is not a server redirect, it is a client redirect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HttpResponse.Redirect is not actually a server-side redirect.  Setting this in the Response stream actually sends a 302 "Moved Temporarily" response to the browser, instructing it to try another URL ("anotherroute").

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not want that behavior, you can use Server.Transfer(url);
There is a good explanation about it here:
http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641/ServerTransfer-Vs-ResponseRedirect.htm